# How to change a local-server IP address to public IP address

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have just looked at this [reference](https://top5hosting.co.uk/blog/uk-hosting/356-how-to-turn-your-old-pc-into-a-linux-ubuntu-server) which is a guide helps to change your old computer to the server, I did everything now my computer is actually a server, but here is a problem I can only exchange or connect to my server on the same router how can I make my server IP address to **Public IP address**?

Comment: What is your goal? Access remotely to your computer from anywhere or just change the IP address?

Comment: I want to make a home server but this will allow only people on the same router to access and communicate with that server, what I want here to make it public and everyone can access it from everywhere in the world, is that possible?

Comment: You need another application to access to your server remotely. So OpenVPN might be a solution. This solution is fine for security. You can take your time to read carefully this link https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/openvpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ibrahim, if you have a router that have ip public, you can use port forwarding to specific port on that server you have been configured.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: Thanks, this problem confused me, I did not fully understand this topic but now it is clear